# MySQL optimization for SELECT FROM multiple tables with quite some AND operations?

Tags: sql, mysql, performance, query-optimization

This query takes about 5 - 10 seconds to run which is unacceptable for rendering a web page:

```
SELECT part . * , brand . * 
FROM  `part` ,  `model2year2part` ,  `brand2subcategory2part` ,  `brand2subcategory` ,  `brand` 
WHERE  `model2year2part`.`model2year_id` =  '9521'
AND  `model2year2part`.`part_id` =  `part`.`id` 
AND  `brand2subcategory`.`subcategory_id` =  '1'
AND  `brand2subcategory2part`.`brand2subcategory_id` =  `brand2subcategory`.`id` 
AND  `brand2subcategory2part`.`part_id` =  `part`.`id` 
AND  `brand`.`id` =  `part`.`brand_id`
```

ANSIfied:

```
SELECT p.*, 
       b.* 
  FROM PART p
  JOIN brand b ON b.id = p.brand_id
  JOIN model2year2part m ON m.part_id = p.id
  JOIN brand2subcategory2part b2p ON b2p.part_id = p.id 
  JOIN brand2subcategory b2 ON b2.id = b2.brand2subcategory_id
 WHERE m.model2year_id = '9521'
   AND b2.subcategory_id = '1'
```

No matter what you feed to `model2year2part`.`model2year_id` and `brand2subcategory`.`subcategory_id` as input.

**EXPLAIN results of the query**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYtXl.jpg

I have done all possible indexing / unique indexing for all the 5 tables.

- **part**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9z2Mm.jpg
- **model2year2part**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeLMY.jpg
- **brand2subcategory2part**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkI5n.jpg
- **brand2subcategory**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbygX.jpg
- **brand**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfO33.jpg

The number of total records in each table:

- **part**: 728,534
- **model2year2part**: 15,012,595 (is this the culprit?)
- **brand2subcategory2part**: 729,030
- **brand2subcategory**: 8,111
- **brand**: 875

What may be the culprit? Is there any way to optimize this query other than a hardware upgrade?

Comment: Do you really need to return all columns from the two tables?  Are the joins to the category tables really necessary...

Comment: It would help to include the explain plan so we can see what the query optimizer thinks it sees. Just add EXPLAIN before the SELECT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I noticed what looks like a mistake in your fourth Join clause:

`ON b2.id = b2.brand2subcategory_id`

I'm assuming this should be:

`ON b2.id = b2p.brand2subcategory_id`

Second, you might try breaking out the filtering joins from the ones needed for the output. That allows you to do a Explain on just the subquery by itself to see what might be causing the issue:

```
Select P.*, B.*
From Part As P
    Join Brand As B
        On B.Id = P.brand_Id
Where P.part_id In  (
                        Select M1.part_Id
                        From mode2year2part As M1
                                Join brand2subcategory2part As B2P
                                    On B2P.part_id = M1.part_id
                                Join brand2subcategory As B2
                                    On B2.Id = B2P.brand2subcategory_id
                        Where m1.model2year_id = '9521'
                            And B2.subcategory_id = '1'
                        )
```

Comment: MySql don't like subqueryes when used with IN or ANY:

http://jonahellison.com/mysql-subqueries-optimization-and-using-update-inner-joins

Comment: @Calmarius - An inner join is not equivalent to an IN clause. The IN subquery could easily result in multiple rows in the outer query if used as an join. Excluding IN or Exists clauses from your repertoire of tools would severely limit the types of queries you can create. Only actual tests will tell you whether a given query's structure should be changed in order to get better performance.